# Angular 16 inheritates problems with @Injectable

Tags: angular

I've just updated my angular version to v16.
I got the following error message:

The injectable CustomMsalInterceptor inherits its constructor from MsalInterceptor, but the latter does not have an Angular decorator of its own. Dependency injection will not be able to resolve the parameters of MsalInterceptor's constructor. Either add a @Injectable decorator to MsalInterceptor, or add an explicit constructor to CustomMsalInterceptor.

**CustomMsalInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpContextToken,
  HttpHeaders,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';

export const BYPASS_MSAL = new HttpContextToken(() => false);

@Injectable()
export class CustomMsalInterceptor extends MsalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (request.context.get(BYPASS_MSAL)) {
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
        request = request.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
          }),
        });
      }
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    return super.intercept(request, next);
  }
}
```

**MsalInterceptor**

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { MsalService } from "./msal.service";
import { MsalInterceptorConfiguration } from "./msal.interceptor.config";
import { MsalBroadcastService } from "./msal.broadcast.service";

export declare class MsalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private msalInterceptorConfig;
    private authService;
    private location;
    private msalBroadcastService;
    private _document?;
    constructor(msalInterceptorConfig: MsalInterceptorConfiguration, authService: MsalService, location: Location, msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService, document?: any);
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
    /**
     * Try to acquire token silently. Invoke interaction if acquireTokenSilent rejected with error or resolved with null access token
     * @param authRequest Request
     * @param scopes Array of scopes for the request
     * @param account Account
     * @returns Authentication result
     */
    private acquireToken;
    /**
     * Invoke interaction for the given set of scopes
     * @param authRequest Request
     * @param scopes Array of scopes for the request
     * @returns Result from the interactive request
     */
    private acquireTokenInteractively;
    /**
     * Looks up the scopes for the given endpoint from the protectedResourceMap
     * @param endpoint Url of the request
     * @param httpMethod Http method of the request
     * @returns Array of scopes, or null if not found
     *
     */
    private getScopesForEndpoint;
    /**
     * Finds resource endpoints that match request endpoint
     * @param protectedResourcesEndpoints
     * @param endpoint
     * @returns
     */
    private matchResourcesToEndpoint;
    /**
     * Transforms relative urls to absolute urls
     * @param url
     * @returns
     */
    private getAbsoluteUrl;
    /**
     * Finds scopes from first matching endpoint with HTTP method that matches request
     * @param protectedResourceMap Protected resource map
     * @param endpointArray Array of resources that match request endpoint
     * @param httpMethod Http method of the request
     * @returns
     */
    private matchScopesToEndpoint;
}
//# sourceMappingURL=msal.interceptor.d.ts.map
```

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor have an [order of execution](https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses#interceptor-order), you should probably drop the inheritance and create a new one and add after the `MsalInterceptor`.

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true },
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomMsalInterceptor , multi: true },
];
```

Comment: Where do i put the this code? And when removing the extends MsalInterceptor, what should I do about the return super.intercept(request, next); ?